# cache content that doesn't have a mime or extension

Tags: php, apache, caching

in our website we have a folder that has jpg files . but files don't have the extension . the previous programmer save them like : `service-icon`,`service-medal` without any extension.
if i want to let apache cache the content , i need to know the extension so i can get them with `filesMatch` or i need to know the mime type of file so i can get them using `ExpiresByType`. 
i can rename all the files and have to change them `everywhere` they used and i prefer not to add the extension to them !. is there any way so i can cache the content in the directory without changing the files and add extension ?

---

ps : in the folder i have some other files that i don't want them to cache. i just want the files without extension cache.